# Data Cleaning - Basic questions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter, data-cleaning

```
sal_mod = sal[['Salary']]
f=lambda x : x.replace('K','000')
sal_mod = sal_mod.apply(f,axis=1)
sal_mod.head(20)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA5HV.jpg)

I run this code in the hope that I will be able remove the k from every row of the column, But Now I am sweating over it. Please help. IDK what is going wrong.

Maybe this helps - when I use :

```
f=lambda x: x.lower()
```

in the code above : 
this is the error that pops up :

```
Series' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

the data :

```
          Salary
0   ₹752K - ₹828K
1   ₹423K - ₹462K
2   ₹622K - ₹671K
3   ₹28K - ₹30K
4   ₹23K - ₹25K
5   ₹395K - ₹2,069K
6   ₹950K - ₹3,086K
7   ₹695K - ₹741K
8   ₹583K - ₹639K
9   ₹57K - ₹62K
```

Based on a few comments I was able to clean the data to some extent:

```
sal_mod = sal[['Salary']]
f=lambda x : x.str.replace('K','000').str.replace('₹','').str.replace(',','')
sal_mod = sal_mod.apply(f,axis=1)
sal_mod = pd.Series(sal_mod['Salary'],dtype="string")
sal_mod.head(20)
```

The following code dosent execute :

```
sal_min = sal_mod.apply((lambda x: x.split('-')),axis=1)
sal_min.head(20)
```

Can I change the data type to string, because I hit a snag after a few successful str.replace(..) I want to use split function but the result of the split function is not scriptable/iterable. it is probably because it is a text object as of now! I want to be able to convert it to integer

Comment: `lower` is a string methods, you need to use the string accessor, `.str.lower()`. See [Working with Text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)

Comment: can you add your source data as text? IIUC `df['Salary'].str.replace('K', '000')`

Comment: It worked, using string accessor in the lambda function

Comment: Can I change the data type to string, because I hit a snag after a few successful str.replace(...)

I want to use split function but the result of the split function is not scriptable/iterable... it is probably because of the text data type